# Swift get Fraction of Float

Tags: objective-c, math, swift, type-conversion

I've been trying out swift lately and i've come across a rather simple Problem.

In Obj-C when i want to get the fraction digits of a float i'd do the following:

```
float x = 3.141516
int integer_x = (int)x;
float fractional_x = x-integer_x;
//Result: fractional_x = 0.141516
```

in Swift:

```
let x:Float = 3.141516
let integerX:Int = Int(x)
let fractionalX:Float =  x - integerX
```

-> this results in an error because of mismachting types

Any Idea how to do it correctly?

Thanks in Advance

Malte

Comment: There is no automatic conversions in Swift besides literals. So Swift doesn't let you do math with x, a Float and integerX, an Int. You need to convert it back to a float: x - Float(integerX). But have a look at my answer below, I feel it should suit you better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot subtract Float and Int, you should convert one of this value to be the same as another, try that:

```
let fractionalX:Float = x - Float(integerX)
```

Answer (score 14):

Use the `modf` function:

```
let v = 3.141516
var integer = 0.0
let fraction = modf(v, &integer)
println("fraction: \(fraction)");
```

output:

> fraction: 0.141516

For float instead of double just use: `modff`

Comment: modf actually returns a tuple.

Comment: No, it returns a double: `double modf(double value, double *iptr);` , see: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man3/modf.3.html

Comment: yes, it does return a tuple. Click on Darwin and look at the function: func modf(value: Double) -> (Double, Double) . (The documentation is not up to date I guess. Who reads the documentation anyway.)

Comment: @fabrice show your reference. Also if you don't like my answer feel free to add your own answer, completely changing my answer is not acceptable. Your `mod` function is **not** the one I used.

Comment: You are both right. There is `func modf(_: Double, _: UnsafePointer<Double>) -> Double` **and** `func modf(value: Double) -> (Double, Double)` and also Float variants. The former is imported from `<math.h>`, the latter seems to be Swift only.

Comment: I do not see the no tuple version in the Darwin module. Swift beta 4. It doesn't play nice in a playground either (extra argument error).

Comment: I can confirm that both `let (a, b) = modf(x)` and `let d = modf(x, &c)` work in a compiled app and in my playground file. - Actually I find `let (a, b) = modf(x)` more elegant, but your code compiles and works without problems for me.

Comment: Sorry if I offended you, I wasn't trying to start a war or anything. My reference is the header you get when command-clicking on import Darwin. Your code doesn't compile in my Xcode 6 beta 4, it gives an extra argument error. Hence my edit. What Xcode version are you using?

Comment: Actually the code does compile in a Swift project, I actually ran it to get the result. However as you mention if doses not compile in the playground.

Comment: @Zaph: There should be no space after `&`. Apart from that, it compiles even in my playground.

Comment: I like your Darwin mod code that returns a tuple, why not add it to your answer.

Comment: thanks for the info! i didn't even knew there was such a function! Since Greg was faster and his answer is more suited to my code it marked his answer as correct. But since i haven't got 15 rep i can't up vote your answer aswell. Stupid system.

Answer (score 9):

Use `.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy:)` which replaced the modulo operator (**x % 1**), which (for modulo)

- immediately (it is only one character), and
- with few cpu cycles (presumably only one cycle, since modulo is a common cpu instruction)

gives the fractional part.

```
let x:Float = 3.141516
let fracPart =  x.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1) // fracPart is now 0.141516
```

`fracPart` will assume the value: **0.141516**. This works for `double` and `float`.

Answer (score 4):

Swift 3 does not like the modulus operator `%`. It wants me to use `truncatingRemainder` of `Double` type.

```
let x1:Double = 123.00
let t1 = x1.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1)
print("t1 = \(t1)")
let x2:Double = 123.45
let t2 = x2.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1)
print("t2 = \(t2)")
```

Produces output:

```
t1 = 0.0
t2 = 0.450000000000003
```

To remove the 3 quadrillionth artifact you should probably round the result.

Answer (score -1):

Why using an int whatsoever?

What about this instead:

```
import Darwin

let x = 3.1415926
let xf = x - (x > 0 ? floor(x) : ceil(x))
```

It will use doubles by default here. Feel free to use floats if it's what you need:

```
let x: Float = 3.1415926
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Because the question is about the fraction of a float only.

Comment: let ( _ , fraction ) = modf(x) works too, whatever floats your boat.